# Naming convention for "data"'s with multiple constructors

Tags: haskell

What's the naming convention for long data's with multiple constructors? How can I format this?

```
data MyData = 
  MyData1 
    { var1 :: Int
    , var2 :: String
    , var3 :: String
    , var4 :: String
    , var5 :: String
    , var6 :: String
    , var7 :: String
    , var8 :: String
    } |
  MyData2 
    { var1 :: Int
    , var2 :: String
    , var3 :: String
    , var4 :: String
    } |
  MyData3 
    { var3 :: String
    , var4 :: String
    }
```

I haven't found anything about this.

UPDATE:

I mean, how can I place the constructors and fields and the "|". One line, different line? What exactly on one line, what on different line?

Comment: The convention is to use names in normal English that reflect what the data type is actually supposed to _mean._

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think that qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The convention is to use names in normal English that reflect what the data type is actually supposed to *mean.*  What does this data represent?  What are the meanings of the fields?  What is `var1` used to store?

Name your fields after the answer.

Comment: Oh, _formatting_?  However you think is most readable.  There's no generally agreed upon style there.

Answer (score 1):

For formatting, it's commonly recommended to align `=` and `|` (e.g. https://github.com/chrisdone/haskell-style-guide#data-types and https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md#data-declarations):

```
data MyData = MyData1 
                { var1 :: ...
                , var2 :: ...
                }
            | MyData2 ...
```

or

```
data MyData 
  = MyData1 { var1 :: ...
            , var2 :: ...
            }
  | MyData2 ...
```